# Chainer: How do I remove all elements below the mean from an array?

Tags: arrays, neural-network, chainer

I have an array in Chainer and I want to remove all the elements that are either 0 or below the mean.

So for example, given the array [0,1,2,3] I want to end up with the array [1]. With Tensorflow, this is possible with tf.gather, but I coulnd't find the Chainer equivalent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "above" the mean?